# Fastest way to send HTTP Post in C#

Tags: c#, performance, sockets, http, tcp

We are sending a lot of push messages using HTTP Post.

First, we used HttpWebRequest / WebClient, and messages arrived to client, but sometime it took 400ms for single message.

We switched for TCP/IP (sockets), we just send the message and that it, didnt do any receive for the replay, etc. Messages were sent in 40ms avg.

The problem with the TCP/IP (sockets) was that not all messages arrived, sometime We sent (e.g.) ABCDEFG and client received only ABCD (not 100% of the data), this is not happening when we use HttpWebRequest / WebClient.

So, to sum up everything:

1. HttpWebRequest / WebClient - Very reliable but slow.
2. TCP/IP (Sockets) - Not reliable and fast.

Any other solution I can use maybe?

Comment: Before looking into this, how many requests/sec can your server sustain (that is, if it is yours)?

Comment: Oh, right, my bad, forgot to mention. We send around 1000 requests per second. And thats a dedicated server with 10GB uplink running Windows 2K8 R2

Comment: How large is one message? Would it fit into a TCP packet of 'normal' size (around 1.5KB)?

Comment: Every message is 2kb average. The message we send is XML.

Comment: OK, so the server can sustain a higher rate. With sockets, I think that you may have got other responses than 200 (OK) but missed them since you didn't wait for any response.

Comment: Reading the response will make it same speed as HttpWebRequest, isnt it?

Comment: HTTP doesn't add 360ms of overhead per call. You have prematurely switched to sockets. You have just misdiagnosed HTTP to be the cause of the perf problems. It wasn't. Your code was.

Comment: And now you are prematurely giving up on sockets because *your code* has a bug losing messages (you don't think that TCP will randomly lose data, do you?). Just fix the bugs and both solutions will work (with HTTP being the preferred one).

Comment: Do you open/close the connection for sending/receiving the messages, or are all messages sent over the same established TCP connection (i.e., the same networkstream)?

Comment: Maybe you can show some relevant code, for both HTTP and sockets (if it's not too big). @usr is right, there has to be a problem with your code.

Comment: Elgonzo - We re-open the connection every time we send.

Comment: Okay, i wager a blind guess. It looks like you read a byte array from the network stream. Note that `NetworkStream.Read(byte[], yada-yada)` returns only the data received **so far**. Since a 2KB message does not fit into a single 'normal' TCP packet frame it is possible that the first call of *NetworkStream.Read* returns only the data of the first packet received (the 2nd packet still 'being on its way') -- in such a situation you will need to call *NetworkStream.Read* again until you got all data...